# Blog-like entry methodology

Tags: php, javascript, layout

This may be a well known subject, so excuse me for my lack of knowledge, but I am curious how most article/blog based websites work when it comes to inserting a new "post" or article.  Think of a blog, or a website like cnn.com. Whenever they get a new article they want to post, I am sure they have some kind of user interface that allows them to type in a title, content, upload images, ect, all while maintaining the styling and layout of the rest of the site.

This is opposed to them actually "coding" out a complete page with markup and everything and styling how they want (seeing how most journalists probably don't know markup).  Are there any open source libraries or standard api that people can use or do most blogs and websites like that just create their own from scratch?

Comment: Wordpress is a good example to start with: http://wordpress.org

Comment: Wordpress is the biggest name in the game http://wordpress.com

Comment: It's called a CMS (Content Management System). That should help with the googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org) is easily the most popular free/open source option out there**, for blogging or even general websites. People like it because it makes it **very easy to install, and use, even if you are not technically inclined**. [Wordpress.com](http://Wordpress.com) (not to be confused with Wordpress.org) allows you to create free accounts, hosted by them. In addition, almost every shared host (Dreamhost, hostmonster, etc) have one-click Wordpress installs.

There are other options like **Drupal or Joomla that allow you more control** over what you can do, but this usually comes **at the cost of usability** for the person that has no desire to learn any sort of coding (e.g. photography, cooking blogs).

In addition, **Wordpress has a wide variety of ancilliary benefits** that come along with being the market leader, including:

- Large plug-in support
- Variety of free and paid for themes
- More questions that have already been answered online
- Greater familiarity with developers

Comment: List at least a couple others, their pros/cons and I'll +1. Otherwise, it's not all that helpful...